# Showing number of rows created by each user

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

I need to show the number of entries created by each user in a table named "RE".
Only the non empty entries have to be counted, by a column named "DD".
The result have to be shown in a table.
I already tried to do it like that, but to no avail:

```
<?php
if ($username = 'John Doe') {
    echo "<table>";
    $query = "SELECT user, COUNT(DISTINCT DD) AS number FROM RE GROUP BY user";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {

        foreach ($user[$i] as $field => $value) {

            if ($field == "number") {$number = $value;}
        }
        echo "<tr><td>".$user."</td><td>".$number."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

?>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the query even run?  If so, what is your current output and why is that wrong?

Comment: The query runs, and should show the results in a table. Nothing happens, instead.

Comment: You are not using `$results` anywhere in your code.

Comment: Edited my question. Nothing changed

Comment: Look at the examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, counting distinct may not be what you want, and also you could have empty string, in addition to `NULL` for your "empty entries."  If so, then it might be appropriate to count entries which are non `NULL` and non empty string.

```
SELECT
    user,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(DD, '') <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number
FROM RE
GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to count "non-empty" results is something like this:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(DD) AS number
FROM RE
GROUP BY user;
```

This assumes that "empty" is `NULL`.

Comment: I tried your solution and when the query is executed directly on the database (I'm using Altervista) it works perfectly.
When I try to run it from the page it shows nothing. So, I think I've made a mistake is the rest of the code I've written, but can't find it.